# Hardware update required on Monero mining

Tags: mining, gpu-mining

I am new to mining but after reading and research I am going in with Monero. I am planning to use the Sapphire RX Vega 56 8GB GPU. The motherboard is Asus B250, 8GB RAM. The questions that I have are:

1) After referring to [MoneroBenchmarks](http://monerobenchmarks.info/) it seems that Vega 56 cards provide a really good hashrate at low power. But, are there any better options that I can consider? And, when I select a GPU, what configuration of the GPU should I focus on to know which one will be better. I know that efficiency will vary depending on the algorithm I am processing, but besides that is there anything relating to the GPU's config that I should focus on?
2) Regarding the processor, is there one that I should focus on to increase my efficiency? Since the work will be done by the GPUs primarily, so will the choice of processor play a significant role?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the **AMD Radeon VEGA** cards, both 56 and 64, are the best options for mining Monero. Nothing is comparable to VEGA and with fine tuning you can reach really high hashrate (about 2000H/s) with really low TDP.

To understand how to config **VEGA** and miners, useful sources are:

- [Monero and Vega - the definitive guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/comments/74hjqn/monero_and_vega_the_definitive_guide/)
- [Vega Mining - A
  Consolidated Guide](http://vega.miningguides.com/)

Regarding the processor, **CPU** is not important at all and doesn't play a significant role, but if you have a XEON or a RYZEN you can add nice hashrate to total value also mining with CPU.